# How to retrieve the resultset of COUNT() SUM() AVG() MIN() MAX() statements?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, resultset

I have a problem with my system in retrieving some values on my database. I want to get a summary of the values in the specific fields. This is my code of retrieving the values:

```
public void insertToClientSummary(){
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(genClientID), SUM(principal), SUM(interest), SUM(totalPayment), SUM(totalBal) FROM client_info";
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        String titles[] = new String [4];
        titles[0] = "Total Clients";
        titles[1] = "Total Loan Book";
        titles[2] = "Total Interests";
        titles[3] = "Total Payment";
        titles[4] = "Total Balance";
        rs.next();
        for (int ctr=0;ctr<=5;ctr++){
            String sql2 = "INSERT INTO client_summary (title, sumValues) VALUES ('"+titles[ctr]+"','')";
            PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            stmt2.executeUpdate();
            ctr++;
            sql = "UPDATE client_summary SET sumValues = '"+String.valueOf(rs.getDouble(ctr))+"'";
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            ctr--;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client Summary Query Exception");
    }
}
```

By the way, I also included my codes for inserting new values on the said `client_summary` table. But I think I got exceptions on the first query. Any idea of a proper retrieval of data?

Comment: What is the Database you are using?

Comment: mysql5 and phpMyAdmin is my DBMS

Answer (score 3):

You may use `as name` (alias) to get them. Example

```
SELECT COUNT(genClientID) as cnt, .........
```

Then

```
   rs.getString("cnt");
```

Comment: This is usually called an "_alias_".

Comment: in `rs.get(cnt);` the `cnt` comes an error `cannot find symbol`
when `cnt` is initialized as String then `get` comes an error `cannot find symbol`

Comment: `sql = "SELECT COUNT(genClientID) as clients, SUM(principal) as prin, SUM(interest) as intr, SUM(totalPayment) as totPay, SUM(totalBal) as totBal FROM client_info";
        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.first();
            rs.get("clients");`
the `get` symbol couldn't be found

Comment: @JayMarz: Why there is single quote ?

Comment: @JayMarz: It should be getString("clients"); not get("Clients");

Comment: Yes I did it like that. Still exception occurred. sql = `"SELECT COUNT(genClientID) as clients, SUM(principal) as prin, SUM(interest) as intr, SUM(totalPayment) as totPay, SUM(totalBal) as totBal FROM client_info";
        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString("clients"));` the message dialog is not popping.

Answer (score 1):

You may use insert select if you just want to insert the aggregated values in a summary table.
That way you would not need the result set iteration. e.g

```
INSERT INTO summary(id,total,max) SELECT count(id),sum(principal),sum(interest) FROM client_info
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesnt work for me. I dont known if I have some problem in SQL query, but if I run it on database it returns right value.

```
SELECT ((SUM(Y1) * 20) / 60) as heat FROM logger.AcondData where (time > '2013-10-12 0:0:0' and time < '2013-10-12 23:59:59') and Y1 = 1 and Y8 = 0;
```

And here is getting from ResultSet.

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = mConnection.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next())
{
    printWriter.println("<h1>Heating time: " + resultSet.getString("heat") + " minut");
}
```

Edit1:
If I remove last two conditions it works.

```
SELECT ((SUM(Y1) * 20) / 60) as heat FROM logger.AcondData where (time > '2013-10-12 0:0:0' and time < '2013-10-12 23:59:59');
```

Y1 and Y8 are TINYINT(1)

Edit2:
Now its working, It looks like the problem was in database data. After import of data from remote database its OK.